# How to run a CPU Hogging Program on Remote Server?

Tags: ssh

I am about to run a machine learning program which might take a day or two to complete; I do not want to run it on my laptop, but on a remote server. Now I am thinking if I ssh into the machine and run the program there, and close the ssh session, how will I know next time I ssh into the machine if the program is still running or completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `screen` instead.  Assuming you have it installed, just run `screen` from the ssh session.  You will be given a new shell.

Once you start the program you can detach the session from your terminal by typing `^a d` (CTRL+a followed by d).

Later, when you ssh back in, run `screen -r` to reattach the session to your current terminal.

(Note that just plain killing off the ssh session will in fact also detach the screen session, not kill it.)

`man screen` for further reading.  `screen` is **very** powerful, and learning the `^a` action sequences would be well worth your time.  I use `screen` daily and love it.